# How to integrate vue tours in nested components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, quasar-framework

I have multiple nested components, how to set the ids which should be trigged when then element belongs to child component, in Vue tours. Though i have instantiated and added all the steps in the parent component.

Using:
"vue-tour": "^2.0.0",and vue 2 with quasar framework

Tried adding id to the child component but it doesn't suffice the solution as it doesn't render , nor it works on the exact element on which i would like to render

Comment: An example code would help to debug this issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: <template>
......
<div id="hello" class="container-wrap" @scroll="handleScroll">
          <detailPageInfo
            id="detailInfo"
            :isCampground="true"
            :isHike="false"
/>
</template>


This way there are multiple child components within this parent component and i am using vue tours, but i am unable to achieve and point to elements of child component.